# Save an image from canvas to WordPress media library (or server)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, canvas, media-library

I am trying to implement functionality that allows users to save a png generated on a canvas element into a WordPress media library, or at least on the server (this is an intermediate step to sharing the image on facebook, which requires a valid image URL).

So far, I've just been doing everything with JavaScript, and am trying to save the image to the server with an AJAX call. So far, this is my AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click','.facebook',function(e){

var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imageURL = image.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myexample.com",
  data: { 
 imgBase64: imageURL
}
}).done(function(o) {
 console.log('saved'); 
});
```

I guess I'm also a little unsure as to what is supposed to go in my url....I tried using the path for the images in my actual media library, but got a "permission denied" error when I tried to execute this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There should be admin ajax URL. you can use the ajaxurl javascript variable to reference the admin-ajax.php file. However this variable is not declared on the frontend. It is simple to declare this on the front end, by putting the following in the header.php of your theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

Then use it in your script like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.facebook',function(e){

var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imageURL = image.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: { 
 imgBase64: imageURL
}
}).done(function(o) {
 console.log('saved'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if WordPress has a REST API to upload images, so here is another approach: You can create your custom endpoint with the following action [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/)

Inside the function you can handle the image upload, heres an example of how to create a custom REST endpoint (http://example.com/imageHandler/v1/upload with type POST).

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( '/imageHandler/v1', '/upload', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'uploadImage',
    ) );
} );

function uploadImage($request) {
    $base64Image = $request['imgBase64'];
}
```

Inside the uploadImage function you might want to try this solution for uploading base64 images: https://gist.github.com/tjhole/3ddfc6cbf6da01c7ce0f since WordPress alone can't handle base64 uploads.

After uploading you can return the image url by calling: [wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)